# Unable to debug controller in Springboot

Tags: rest, spring-boot, debugging, model-view-controller

I am trying to debug my code on my **local** machine. I started my app on debug method and sent a request through the browser. For some reason it does not hit the breakpoint which is in controller but it hits the breakpoint which is in service class which is used inside controller. What can be reason for it ?

Additionally, when I start my app in debug mode, I see that two terminals are opened.

My controller is :

```
   public class MyController{

        private final MyService myService;

        @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
        @ApiOperation("Returns by identifier")
        public ResponseEntity<MyDTO> getById(@PathVariable("id") final Long id) {
            val myObj= myService.findById(id); // here is breakpoint
            return ResponseEntity.ok(myObj);
        }
    }
```

My service class is

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyServiceImp implements MyService{

  private final ModelMapper modelMapper;
    private final MyRepository myRepository;


  @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public MyDTO findById(final Long id) {
        return myRepository.findById(id)
                .map(myObj-> modelMapper.map(myObj, MyDTO.class))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new QuestionNotFoundException(id));
    }
}
```

and my pom file is :

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.vaadin</groupId>
      <artifactId>vaadin-usage-statistics</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-optout</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
      <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
      <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>13.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
      <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: And where exactly did you put your breakpoint?

Comment: Breakpoint is on the line " val myObj= myService.findById(id);" in the controller's findById method.

Comment: If you look at the call-stack when you are at the break-point in the service does it show the controller, does it bring you there when you click? Could you share a screenshot of that? If you look at the breakpoint when running in debug mode, does it look happy or is it gray or another active color, could you make a screenshot of that? What IDE are you using? Please update your question with those details.

Comment: did you mark the controller class with @controller annotation

Comment: ok guys i found the issue, thanks a lot for your interest.